# React js date is not binding in edit mode

Tags: reactjs, date

I am new to react js, I have date textboxes on the page, for insertion they work fine as they don't need to be prefilled. When I am editing the page, it is filling all the information except the date fields.

I am using below code:

```
class EditStaff extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        id: 0,
        continuousdate: new Date(),
        probationdays: "",
        userstatuscode: "",
        sex: "",
        domainname: "",
        isActive: ""

    };
};

componentDidMount() {

            API.getItems(userdata).then(items => {

                var userDetails = items.user;

                debugger
                this.setState({
                    id: userDetails.id,
                    continuousdate: userDetails.continuousdate, 
                    probationdays: userDetails.probationdays,
                    userstatuscode: userDetails.userstatuscode,
                    sex: userDetails.sex,
                    domainname: userDetails.domainname,
                    isActive: userDetails.isActive,
                });
            });
}


handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const name = target.name;
    if (target.type === 'checkbox') {
        if (target.checked) {
            this.setState({ [name]: 1 });
        } else {
            this.setState({ [name]: 0 });
        }
    } else
        this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
}
render() {
    if (!this.state) {
        <p>  Loading....</p>
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <div className="row">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="infoTabs bd-example-tabs">
                        <div className="" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="basic-info-tab" aria-expanded="true">
                            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>


                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                                        <div className="form-row">
                                            <div className=" form-group col-12">
                                                <div className="Password">
                                                    <label htmlFor="Password" className="text-primary">Password<span className="required">*</span></label>
                                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" maxLength="15" defaultValue={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required />
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-row">
                                            <div className="form-group col-12">
                                                <Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{this.state.continuousdate}</Moment>
                                                <label htmlFor="continuousdate" className="text-primary">continuousdate<span className="required">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="date" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.continuousdate} name="continuousdate" id="continuousdate" placeholder="Enter continuousdate" required />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                                        <div className="form-row">
                                            <div className=" form-group col-12">
                                                <div className="jobstatus">
                                                    <label htmlFor="jobstatus" className="text-primary">Job Status<span className="required">*</span></label>
                                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" maxLength="2" defaultValue={this.state.jobstatus} onChange={this.handleChange} name="jobstatus" id="jobstatus" placeholder="Enter jobstatus" required />
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-row">
                                            <div className="form-group col-12">
                                                <label htmlFor="probationdays" className="text-primary">probationdays<span className="required">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]" className="form-control" maxLength="3" defaultValue={this.state.probationdays} onChange={this.handleChange} name="probationdays" id="probationdays" placeholder="Enter probationdays" required />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                                        <div className="form-row">
                                            <div className=" form-group col-12">
                                                <div className="sex">
                                                    <label htmlFor="sex" className="text-primary">sex<span className="required">*</span></label>
                                                    <select class="form-control" name="sex" value={this.state.sex} required onChange={this.handleChange} >
                                                        {this.state.genderlst.map((gender) => <option key={gender.value} value={gender.value}>{gender.display}</option>)}
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-row">
                                            <div className="form-group col-12">
                                                {/*
                                                <label htmlFor="domainname" className="text-primary">domainname<span className="required">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="text" className="form-control" maxLength="100" onChange={this.handleChange} name="domainname" id="domainname" placeholder="Enter domainname" required />
                                                */}
                                                <label htmlFor="IsActive" className="text-primary">IsActive<span className="required">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={this.state.isActive} defaultValue={this.state.isActive} name="IsActive" id="IsActive" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                                        <div className="form-row">
                                            <div className=" form-group col-12">
                                                {/* <div className="IsActive">
                                                    <label htmlFor="IsActive" className="text-primary">IsActive<span className="required">*</span></label>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={this.state.isActive} name="IsActive" id="IsActive" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                                </div>
                                                */}

                                                <div className="domainname">
                                                    <label htmlFor="domainname" className="text-primary">domainname<span className="required">*</span></label>
                                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" maxLength="100" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.domainname} name="domainname" id="domainname" placeholder="Enter domainname" required />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-row">
                                            <div className="form-group col-12">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save &amp; Next</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        {/*  </div>*/}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

I have tried to pass the static value then it works, it bind the value. then I thought there is some issue with format of the value, I tried number of things, but none of them worked, might be I am not using them in correct way.

Please help, how can I bind the values, any suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the date format, try something like this.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import moment from "moment";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: 0,
      date: new Date().toString()
    };
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value }, () =>
      console.log({ name, value, state: this.state })
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Moment>{this.state.date}</Moment>;
        <br />
        <input
          type="date"
          className="form-control"
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
          value={moment(this.state.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
          name="date"
          id="date"
          placeholder="Enter date"
          required
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```